# Is there something like Google Analytics that I can use?

Tags: node.js, database, data-processing

Recently, I have built functional system that includes Server, Multiple Arduino Modules and front-end of course. I need to Sort my data in the front-end just like Google Analytics do. Can you recommend me a good open-source library that I can use? Currently I'm using NodeORM and the aggregation functions are pretty bad. I cannot even sort my results by Month.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This question probably doesn't belong here - you're asking for software recommendations on a programming help site.

That aside, you could self-host an [ELK](https://www.elastic.co/elk-stack) (**E**lasticsearch, **L**ogstash, **K**ibana) stack and have your devices report to that, then use something like [Grafana](https://grafana.com/) to retrieve and display your data.